# Cannot click or select Control XAML design

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

I develop on VS2010 WPF on Window 7. I have a project that does not throw any error or warning, compile fine, XAML design shows fine except I cannot click or select anyone controls in the XAML design view.

What is the reason, or how can I find out the problem or possible exception?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a UserControl in the design?

Comment: there are no UserControl in the design. But I am user DevExpress - not sure if that is related.

Comment: I had this issue while collapsing the visibility from one of my tabs. Each element inside was "unselectable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reproduced this behavior by putting an empty grid as the last child element of my "main" `Grid`.  In VS2010's designer, I cannot select any of the `Button`s.  Could this be your issue?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="52" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,74,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,100,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" />

        <Grid></Grid>             <!--   THIS IS THE PROBLEM!!!  -->

    </Grid>     
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem, I was able to select controls in the VS2012 WPF project previously but something had changed.

Worked out it was a `TabItem` in a `TabControl`, I had set the visibility to collapsed

```
<TabItem Visibility="Collapsed">
```

to hide the tab header at the top. Setting the `TabItem` visibility back to visible

```
<TabItem Visibility="Visible">
```

allows controls contained in the `TabItem` to be selected in the XAML design view.

Comment: This was the issue with me in VS 2015.

Comment: This was my problem too, tnx

Answer (score 2):

Had this recently, building the project seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Pointer in your toolbox? Sometimes the Pointer item inside the toolbox is gone. So the next item (Border) is selected. So when you try to click, you are actually trying to add a border to the design. You might try resetting the toolbox. But be warned, custom tools are gone then, and have to be added again. (I could not make a comment to this question, so thats the reason I 'answered')

Comment: What do you mean by "Pointer"?

Comment: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1931/ That is what I mean. Hard to explain without that picture, sorry for that. What does your cursor look like when you hover the design area?