# Locked Out Of WPF Designer in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, designer

This is a really odd situation.  I have an application with a number of user controls, and now for some reason when I go into the visual designer in Visual Studio and try to edit the control, I'm locked out,  I can click on the control but nothing happens.  I can go into Expression Blend and edit, but not with Visual Studio.  This is totally random as some user controls are editable and others are not.

Has anybody faced this before, and is there a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're not still running it under the debugger?

Comment: 1. Stop the debugger. 2. Ensure your XAML file is not read only or locked by another process

Comment: I am not running in the debugger.  I can edit the C# file and the XAML.  I just cannot do anything in the visual designer.  If I open the user control in Expression Blend, I can edit, but in Visual Studio, the designer is locked.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Check this question to see if it may be the same issue: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202836/cannot-click-or-select-control-xaml-design